# How to render json data with @ character in its key using handlebars?

Tags: javascript, java, json, handlebars.js

This is my json data

`var data = {john@gmail.com: true}`

In my template i am trying this way to display data but its not working

`{{data.[john@gmail.com]}}`

I even tried this way

`{{data.['john@gmail.com']}}`

and also

`{{data.john@gmail.com}}`

but if i had changed my json data to

`var data = {john:true}`

and try

`{{data.[john]}}`

its working and displaying the output as true

Can anyone please point me where i am making mistake ?

Comment: @filmzy Thank you and i made change to the question :)

Answer (score 1):

It is like this `data["john@gmail.com"]`. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) is a good Resource to read

Comment: I tired that way and i am getting a parse error saying        ` Parse error on line Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'    `